# Unable to draw notification numbers over a Button in v7 toolbar

Tags: android

I'm trying to put a TextView over a Button inside toolbar to show notification count. I have embedded the two into a FrameLayout, which SHOULD respect Z-order, but the TextView continues to be hidden, even if I add .bringToFront() in the code.
Here is my layout (I removed unnecessary attributes and elements):

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
android:id="@+id/bottom_toolbar"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
android:layout_gravity="center"
android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
android:gravity="center"
android:padding="0dp">
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:gravity="center">
    <Button
        ...
    />
    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="68dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <Button
            android:layout_width="68dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Chats"
            android:gravity="bottom|center"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            android:drawableTop="@drawable/ic_question_answer_white_24dp"
            android:id="@+id/buttonChats"
            android:textSize="10dp" />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/badgeView"
            android:layout_width="32dp"
            android:layout_height="32dp"
            android:layout_gravity="top|right"
            android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
            android:background="#af2e00"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:text="16" />
    </FrameLayout> 
</LinearLayout>
```

My suspect is that this attribute:

android:drawableTop="@drawable/ic_question_answer_white_24dp"

is being rendered after and covers the TextView.
Any Hints will be really appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Solved!
I had to add this attribute to TextView:

```
android:elevation="100dp"
```

Weird Android! :/